# print statement is not working in a function

Tags: android, function, flutter, dart, void

If I use `print` in the function `lat()`, it's not getting printed on the console.

Is there any way to prevent such behavior in the function, because I am not able to debug the application?

I am new to Dart/Flutter: I am actually trying to get the `lat` and `long` so that I can send them to an API and get the weather data.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {

    @override
    _Home createState() => _Home();
}

class _Home extends State<Home> {
    int weather = 4;
    dynamic _text;
    dynamic permisson;
    
    void lat() async {
    var pos = await getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high).then((position) { 
    dynamic loc = position.toJson;
    print(loc);

    setState(() { _text = position.toJson(); });
    });

    }
    @override
  void initState()  {
    super.initState();
    lat();
  }
    
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

            Card(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
        Image(
          image: NetworkImage('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl.jpg'),
          height: 250
        ),
        Center(

          child: ListTile(
            
            title: Text(weather.toString()),
            subtitle: Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
          ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('BUY TICKETS'),
                onPressed: () { 
                    setState(() { weather = 4; });

                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 8),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('LISTEN'),
                onPressed: () { 
                    print(_text['longitude']); 
            
                    

                    },
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 8),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),

            ],
            ),
            ),

       bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF6200EE),
          selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.60),
          selectedFontSize: 14,
          unselectedFontSize: 14,
          onTap: (value) {
            print(value);
            if(value == 0) {
              print("home");
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
            } else if (value == 1) {
              print("Settings");
            } else if (value == 2) {
              print("Profile");
            } else if (value == 3) {
              print("About");
            }
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              title: Text('Home'),
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              title: Text('Setting'),
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              title: Text('Profile'),
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              title: Text('About'),
              icon: Icon(Icons.info),
            ),
          ],
        ),

      );
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check where you stand in the application or if your print if working on not or **to check weather your value is null or not**. You should always concat something with your print like:

```
print("My Longitude: ${_text['longitude']}");
```

In print, if you have a single variable like `myVar`, or `myData`, or `myName` then you can use it in print normally like:

```
print(myVar);
print(myData);
print(myName);
```

but if you have want to get values from variables like `_text['longitude']`, `office.employee`, `value.data.name`. You should always use your `Print()` like:

```
print(${value.data.data});
print(${office.employee});
print(_text['longitude']);
```

Comment: i re-framed the question's code the print(loc) is not working